# Yii2 How to create a globally accessible variable that converts user's id to employee's id

Tags: yii2, global-variables, yii2-advanced-app

I have two tables that are related directly in a one-to-one relationship.  One is the standard Yii2 user table (abbreviated field list here for clarity) and the other is the employee table that contains user_id.  How can I create a globally accessible variable (and the actual code to access the employee id) that I can use anywhere in my application that will give me the logged in user's employee id and how would I call that variable?  I wish I could say that I've tried a few things, but unfortunately I am relatively new to Yii2 and have no idea where to start with global variables like this.  Thanks for any help.

user table:
id
username
password
etc

employee table:
id
user_id (related in a one-to-one relationship to the user table)

The Employee Model:

```
<?php

namespace frontend\models\base;

use Yii;

/**
 * This is the base model class for table "employee".
 *
 * @property integer $id
 * @property integer $user_id

 *
 * @property \common\models\User $user
 */
 class Employee extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['user_id', 'required'],
        [['user_id'], 'integer'],
        [['user_id'], 'unique']
    ];
}

public static function tableName()
{
    return 'employee';
}

public function attributeLabels()
{
    return [
        'id' => Yii::t('app', 'ID'),
        'user_id' => Yii::t('app', 'User ID'),
    ];
}

/**
 * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
 */
public function getUser()
{
    return $this->hasOne(\common\models\User::className(), ['id' => 'user_id']);
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe proper way is to use relations in your `User` model. First method is proper relation with activerecord, second one will get id using relation defined above it. so You will add these methods in your User model:

```
/**
 * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
 */
public function getEmployee()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Employee::className(), ['user_id' => 'id']);
}

public function getEmployeeId()
{
    return $this->employee ? $this->employee->id : NULL; // set to NULL or anything you expect to be if record is not found
}
```

Then you can call it like this from everywhere in your app:

```
$employee_id = Yii::$app->user->identity->employeeid;
```

This will only work for User model because it implements Identity, otherwise you would need to instantiate model class first, lets say like this:

```
$user_id = 5; // 5 is id of user record in DB
$user = User::findOne($user_id);
$employee_id = $user->employeeid;
// or using first of 2 relations ...
$employee_id = $user->employee->id;
```

Comment: This suggestion is elegant, simple and worked great for me.  Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

A very simple way is the use of $param array

You can initially config the default value in

```
your_App\config\param.php
```

and accessing using

```
\Yii::$app->params['your_param_key']
```

Looking to your Employee  model (for me ) you don't need  a global var you could simply  use the getUser

```
  $myUser = Employee::user();
```

but you need the param  you can assign using

```
  \Yii::$app->params['my_user'] = Employee::user();
```

or in user

```
  \Yii::$app->params['my_user'] =  Yii::$app->user->id
```

or for retrive the model related to actual user  from table

```
$myEmpModel  =  Employee::find()->where['user_id' =>  Yii::$app->user->id]->one();
```

Comment: Thank you!  But what would the code look like to access the employee id from the logged in user?

Comment: update your question and add .. the employee  model please

Comment: I posted what I assume is the part of the employee model that you need (removed all the irrelevant code to other functions).  If you need more, just let me know.  The question was updated before to include clarification on the code request.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Thanks, but I think your code would return the user id correct?  I need the employee id (from the employee table) of the currently logged in user.  Maybe I misunderstood.

Comment: Thanks!  I think that will work just fine.  I'll accept your answer on that assumption.  I'm sorry but I don't have enough rep (need three more) to upvote your answer.  I wish that I could give you 10 upvotes for it though.  Happy Holidays.

Comment: @Marko   many thanks  .. now you have rep  ..  for upvote..  but above all I reciprocate the good wishes of Merry Christmas and Happy New Year